# The function getAllTelephones strange behavior

Tags: typescript, typeorm

## Objective

I have three tables called `clients`, `contacts`, and `telephones`. I have one route that to return all telephones depending on the `client.id` or `contact.id` if I pass one `client.id` I hope that returns me all telephones from this `client` and at the same to `contacts`. But does not working this. I pass the `client.id` returns me all telephones but if is `contact.id` returns me an empty array. If I change the if place, returns me the `contacts` telephones, but `client` telephones come an empty.

## Sequence

### telephones.routes.ts

```
telephonesRouter.get('/:id', telephonesController.index);
```

### TelephonesController.ts

```
public async index(request: Request, response: Response): Promise<Response> {
    const { id } = request.params;

    try {
      const telephoneService = container.resolve(GetTelephoneService);

      const telephones = await telephoneService.execute({ id });

      return response.status(200).json({ telephones });
    } catch (err) {
      return response.status(400).json({ error: err.message });
    }
  }
```

### GetTelephoneService.ts

```
import { injectable, inject } from 'tsyringe';

import AppError from '@shared/errors/AppError';

/* Interface */
import IClientsRepository from '@modules/clients/repositories/IClientsRepository';
import IContactsRepository from '@modules/contacts/repositories/IContactsRepository';
import ITelephonesRepository from '../repositories/ITelephonesRepository';
import Telephone from '../infra/typeorm/entities/Telephone';

interface IRequest {
  id: string;
}

@injectable()
class GetTelephoneService {
  constructor(
    @inject('TelephonesRepository')
    private telephonesRepository: ITelephonesRepository,

    @inject('ClientsRepository')
    private clientsRepository: IClientsRepository,

    @inject('ContactsRepository')
    private contactsRepository: IContactsRepository,
  ) {}

  public async execute({ id }: IRequest): Promise<Telephone[] | undefined> {
    const isContact = await this.contactsRepository.findContact(id);

    if (isContact !== undefined) {
      const telephones = await this.telephonesRepository.getAllTelephones(id);
      return telephones;
    }

    const isClient = await this.clientsRepository.findClient(id);

    if (isClient !== undefined) {
      const telephones = await this.telephonesRepository.getAllTelephones(id);
      return telephones;
    }
    if (!isContact && !isClient) {
      throw new AppError("We can't found the id", 400);
    }

    return undefined;
  }
}

export default GetTelephoneService;
```

### TelephonesRepository.ts

```
public async getAllTelephones(
    owner_id: string,
  ): Promise<Telephone[] | undefined> {
    const getTelephoneClient = await this.ormRepository.find({
      where: { client_id: owner_id },
    });

    console.log('getTelephoneClient', getTelephoneClient);

    const getTelephoneContact = await this.ormRepository.find({
      where: { contact_id: owner_id, client_id: null },
    });

    console.log('getTelephoneContact', getTelephoneContact);

    if (getTelephoneClient !== undefined) {
      return getTelephoneClient;
    }

    if (getTelephoneContact !== undefined) {
      return getTelephoneContact;
    }

    return undefined;
  }
```

At the `TelephonesRepository.ts` if I pass `getTelephoneClient` first if. Will returns the telephones that the client has. But if I pass `contact.id` the `getTelephoneContact` come empty. If I invert, invert the behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I did was at the `if's` I saw that they will never be `undefined` they will contain `data` or will be an empty array because the return always be `Telephone[] | undefined`. So I verified if the `array` length is different 0.